# Positioning of background images of the page

Tags: css, html

I have two images one image is with dimension 1800 X 1140 and other fade image of dimension 1 X 1140.I need to combine these two images such that the first image should come for half and the second image should be like a gradient which fades the first image.I implemented divs as follows.

```
<div style="background:url('first-img.png') no-repeat fixed top center transparent;">
   <div style-"background:url('second-img.png') repeat fixed bottom center transparent;">

   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the method you used is correct flip the vertical and horizontal position of the bg image.. the correct order is horizontal first and vertical second the code will be like this

```
<div style="background:url('first-img.png') no-repeat fixed center top transparent;">
   <div style-"background:url('second-img.png') repeat fixed center top transparent;">

   </div>
</div>
```

and also add the exact width and height for the div's

Answer (score 0):

hey now you can define position relative and absolute as like this

```
Define your parent postion relative and child define absolute
```

**Css**

```
    .parent{
position:relative;
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    border:solid 1px green;
    background:url('first-img.png') no-repeat fixed top center transparent;
}




.child{
position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    border:solid 2px red;
    background:url('second-img.png') repeat fixed bottom center transparent;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="parent">
       <div class="child">
    -------
       </div>
    </div>
```

Change width and height according to your design ...